# A confusion about webcontrol scope in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, custom-controls, master-pages

**A custom control inside my Masterpage**, Does that can access the main page?

Please help! 
This is my code.

```
namespace TVSSystem
{
    public partial class ControlTVS1 : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        Page abc;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            abc = this.Page; //Control: I suposse that I can access all controls of my page
        }


        protected void Image1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {
        ContentPlaceHolder cph = (ContentPlaceHolder)abc.FindControl("ContentPlacerHolder1");

       TextBox txt = (TextBox)cph.FindControl("TextBox1");
       Button btn = (Button)cph.FindControl("Button3");
       txt.Visible = true;
       btn.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Solved. 
http://forums.asp.net/t/1000865.aspx/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`Page`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.page.aspx) property to access the page containing this user control (no matter if you placed it inside a masterpage):

```
public partial class WebUserControl1 : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var page = this.Page;
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I did so, but throws NullReferenceException.

Comment: What did you do more precisely? Could you show some code? It's hard for me to guess.

Comment: The FindControl method is not recursive. So it won't work unless the control you are looking for is a direct descendant of the Page. You could write a recursive FindControl method: http://geekswithblogs.net/QuandaryPhase/archive/2009/05/06/asp.net-recursive-findcontrol-amp-extension-methods.aspx

Comment: I solved, all that I have to do is here: http://forums.asp.net/t/1000865.aspx/1. Thanks bro.